# Sparql Query Vizualization

Tags: javascript, sparql, visualization, graph-visualization, information-visualization

i'm currently working on a visualizer for SPARQL-queries. Yes, the focus lies on the visualization of the queries and not the results. It might be easy to visualize the results of a query, but how to visualize the query itself when you have more complicated features to consider like filters, group by's etc..

This question is more about inspirations, because i would not have problems in implementing the visualization in Javascript, but rather struggle in ideas how to make them understandably visible.

Thanks for links, ideas, papers, etc..

Comment: StackOverflow is definitely the wrong platform to ask for inspiration.

Comment: I've seen for some other graph database technologies the "Arrow Tool" being used to visually generate queries: http://www.apcjones.com/arrows/ .
However I think this is more a question for the https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ site.

Comment: @Leo, [an example](http://swat.cse.lehigh.edu/projects/lubm/lubm.jpg).

Comment: @Stanislav,

Thankyou, i already thought of those ways to implement the vizualition, but where it gets really difficult is how to visualize a filter f.e. or 'Describe x'.

I don't think Stackoverflow is the wrong platform to ask for inspiration, since it also enables ones broadening of mind, by inspiration of others, i.e. by exchanging solutions for a problem that could be source code or uml or whatever.

Sorry for my english